# jqGrid add class ui-state-disabled doesn't disable action

Tags: button, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid v 5.1.0 using the Bootstrap style. When I apply ui-state-disabled class to a pager button (add) the button looks disabled but when clicked it still processes the event. In previous version this use to disable the event as well. Using latest FF and IE. Any ideas? Thank you.

Edit - add snippet of code that initializes the grid (child). Notice second line from end where the add button is disabled. The button appears disabled but when clicked the event is executed.

Edit 2 - So after much pain and tears I create two fiddles. [One](http://jsfiddle.net/Spidey/52efkrq3/) demonstrates proper disabling of the edit button and [Two](http://jsfiddle.net/Spidey/c6860ev8/) is the same code but using Bootstrap. The edit button is not disabled.

```
        // Water Source grid options...
        var source_gridOptions = {
                caption: 'Associated Water Source(s)',
                data: sourceData,
                datatype: 'local',
                //url: "", // updated dynamically
                //mtype: "GET",
                styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
                colModel: [
                           { label: 'Source ID', name: 'ID', key: true, width: 28 },
                           { label: 'Case ID', name: 'WATER_CASE_ID', width: 28, hidden: true },
                           { label: 'Intake Name', name: 'INTAKE_SOURCE_NAME', width: 50 },
                           { label: 'Intake Type', name: 'INTAKE_SOURCE_TYPE', width: 30 },
                           { label: 'Source Type', name: 'SOURCE_TYPE', width: 20 },
                           { label: 'Water Type', name: 'WATER_TYPE', width: 20 },
                           { label: 'Notes', name: 'NOTES', width: 50 },
                           { label: 'Verified', name: 'VERIFIED', width: 25 },
                ],
                viewrecords: true,
                height: 'auto',
                width: initTabWidth, //dynamically set...
                rowNum: 5,
                pager: "#sourcePager",
                gridComplete: function() {

                } // end grid complete event
        };
        // define CRUD options...
        var source_editOptions = {};
        var source_addOptions = {};
        var source_deleteOptions = {};
        // init Water Source grid...
        $("#sourceGrid").jqGrid(source_gridOptions).navGrid("#sourcePager",{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:false},source_editOptions,source_addOptions,source_deleteOptions);
        $("#add_sourceGrid").addClass('ui-state-disabled'); // <-- disable button
    }); // end grid
```

Comment: Perhaps you could assemble a jsfiddle/jsbin snippet to show your real problem? (i.e. dependencies, markup and how you apply a class to a pager button?)

Comment: @miha I added the code snippet per your request.

Comment: it is still very hard to know what's going on with your code, as there is a lot missing. Perpare something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/ynw3c/) or fork this one... Perhaps you could consult the documentation on [how to prepare a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @miha I added links to two fiddles that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your demo, I was able to figure it out. You actually need to add the `ui-disabled` class to work, not just `disabled` that you've added.

I've modified your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/c6860ev8/16/

You can see in the jqGrid source file which classes are required for bootstrap integration here: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/7901d7b7da969de1ca98282c60e335e013dc31ee/js/grid.base.js#L1035

Hope this helps!

Comment: By add "ui-disabled" that certainly fixed the issue. Thanks so much for taking time to figure it out.